# @Lob annotation JPA Buddy creates a script with the attribute of type TEXT

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, jpa-buddy

I encountered a bug when creating an init script from the java classes for flyway with a postgresql database. If you have an attribute of type string with the @Lob annotation jpa buddy creates a script with the attribute of type TEXT. Hibernate expects this to be of type oid because postgresql stores large objects in a separated table.

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 (Ultimate Edition); JPA Buddy2022.5.2-222; Spring Boot 2.7.7; flyway 9.10.2; Postgresql 15.1

What should I do to make it generate OID?

Comment: If you have an attribute of type string with the @Lob annotation jpa buddy creates a script with the attribute of type TEXT

Comment: What is the java type of the property? Text is a string, and with Postgres, doesn't need to be marked as a lob. Do you really want an OID? Let Hibernate generate the DDL instead of JPA Buddy then.

Comment: @K.Nicholas, thank you for helping us with answering the questions. Ping us via info@jpa-buddy.com to get your free JPA Buddy license as an active community member :)

Comment: @Chris, thank you for helping us with answering the questions. Ping us via info@jpa-buddy.com to get your free JPA Buddy license as an active community member :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Type Mappings Settings (Tools -> JPA Buddy -> Database Versionong -> Type Mappings)
2. Select postgresql type
3. Add custom Mapping Type for the `jakarta.persistence.Lob` or `javax.persistence.Lob` or `java.lang.LobString` and mapping to `oid` SQL type

See the picture below:
[image]